# How can we add inputs when total number of inputs are not known using strings in Python?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I could get the inputs but don't know how to add them.
This is what I tried:

```py
n = int(input("enter the total number to find average"))

for i in range (0, n):
    i = int(input("enter the number {i} here"))
```

Comment: I'm sure you know how to add two numbers together. What if you were to first start a running total: `total = 0`?

Comment: its the same operator you'd usually use for additions - `+`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be able to have an arbitrary number of inputs you can use a while loop and a break condition

```
numbers = []
i = 1
while True:
    try:
        numbers.append(int(input(f"enter number {i} (enter blank to end):")), inplace=True)
    except ValueError:
        break
```

in this way you can store as many or few inputs as the user wishes to provide in a list and then perform the rest of the script on that list

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
n = int(input("enter the total number to find average"))
s=0     #a varaiable to store sum
for i in range (1, n+1):
    i = int(input("enter the number {} here ".format(i)))
    s+=i
print('The sum of all the numbers entered by you is :', s)
```